# My code which uses UpdateLayeredWindow doesn't work

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi+

I attampted to draw a irregular window with the UpdateLayeredWindow(), in msvc2008, xp sp3.
Here is part of my code:

```
//Add something(CreateWindowEx()):
hwndCyauWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    /*WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW |*/ WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_LAYERED,
    lpwsCyauClassName,
    lpwsCyauWndName,
    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_POPUP,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)-320,
    GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)-232,
    320, 200,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

//Skip Lines
HDC hdcCyauWnd = GetDC(hwndCyauWnd);
HDC hdcBuffer = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcCyauWnd);
//HBITMAP hbmCyau = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcBuffer,120, 93);
//SelectObject(hdcBuffer, hbmCyau);

POINT ptZero = {0, 0};
POINT ptDrawPos = {0, 0};
RECT rctCyauWnd;
GetWindowRect(hwndCyauWnd, &rctCyauWnd);
SIZE szCyauWnd={rctCyauWnd.right - rctCyauWnd.left, rctCyauWnd.bottom - rctCyauWnd.top};
BLENDFUNCTION blendPixelFunction = { AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 100, AC_SRC_ALPHA};

Graphics gphCyauWnd(hdcBuffer);
Image imgCyau(L"surface0000.png");
gphCyauWnd.DrawImage(&imgCyau, 0, 0, 125, 93);

UpdateLayeredWindow(hwndCyauWnd,
    hdcCyauWnd, &ptZero,
    &szCyauWnd,
    hdcBuffer, &ptZero,
    0, //RGB(255, 255, 255),
    &blendPixelFunction,
    ULW_ALPHA);

while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))    
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return msg.wParam;
```

I have tried several method to use this function, but all failed, NOTHING APPEAR on the screen.
Could anybody tell me what happens and how to slove it?

Add:
Whole source file have been upload to [my skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ad741b27120b92fd&resid=AD741B27120B92FD!195&parid=AD741B27120B92FD!160&authkey=!AK-l6sOqayj5Q_A), anyone can edit, much appreciation! (I have become a poor underdog now...)

Comment: Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556.aspx), the window you pass as the first parameter to the `UpdateLayeredWindow` function must have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style specified when it is created with the `CreateWindowEx` function. And on versions of Windows prior to 8, that window must be a top-level window (Windows 8 supports the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style for top-level windows *and* child windows.)

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, sorry. I left behind some lines. hwndCyauWnd already have WS_ES_LAYERED style before the block. So it should work, but it didn't. That is why I am confused.

Comment: Hmm, do be sure to edit the question and add in those lines that you left out. Particularly the ones where you call `CreateWindowEx` to create the window. Questions like this one (where you're asking for someone to help you debug your code) should really include a small, self-contained demo project that we can run ourselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mixed up GDI and GDI+, which is not a good idea. Here is a working example:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, szWindowClass, szTitle, 0,
     CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

// Load PNG
CImage img;
img.Load("BACKGR.png");
// Get image sizes
int nWidth = img.GetWidth();
int nHeight = img.GetHeight();
// Create memory DC
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
// Create memory bitmap
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, nWidth, nHeight);
HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDC, hBmp);
// Draw image to memory bitmap (currently selected in memory DC)
img.Draw(hDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);

// Call UpdateLayeredWindow
BLENDFUNCTION blend = {0};
blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 128;// half transparent
blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
POINT ptLocation = {0, 0};
SIZE szWnd = {nWidth, nHeight};
POINT ptSrc = {0, 0};
UpdateLayeredWindow(hWnd, hdcScreen, &ptLocation, &szWnd, hDC, &ptSrc, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

SelectObject(hDC, hBmpOld);
DeleteObject(hBmp);
DeleteDC(hDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
```

Comment: Errr...,something wrong with `img.Draw(hDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);` Trace it and found it stop at `inline void CImage::ReleaseDC() const throw(){ATLASSERT( hBitmap == m_hBitmap );}`  The window is still unseen, even can't caught by Spy++

Comment: Sorry, somehow ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW) slipped from the code, see edited answer. After adding this, all is working fine on my side. Are you sure your png file is OK?

Comment: Still not work, and even I can't tell what happened... I have uploaded the code to skydrive, would you please help me a bit more? A lot of appreciation!

Comment: Err.., it's in the Question block. And here is a copy: [Link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ad741b27120b92fd&resid=AD741B27120B92FD!195&parid=AD741B27120B92FD!160&authkey=!AK-l6sOqayj5Q_A)

Comment: You have a typo: it should be :HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcCDC, hbmpCyau); and not  SelectObject(hdcCDC, imgCyau);   - this is the reason for assertion. And there are some more flaws in your code that are out of the scope of this question. Please start from the example in my answer, it should work, and then add other things you need.

Comment: How to say... More trouble... And I have aborted to use VC. Thanks for your effort to help me, through I still fail to achieve it. So I must apologize for my foolishness... Great honor to your kind mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want GDI+ to draw to an image with an alpha channel, you have to draw to a Bitmap, not an HDC, and you have to specify that the Bitmap's format has alpha. To do that with an HBITMAP, you have to also point GDI+ to the bitmap bits.

Something like this:

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
HBITMAP hbmp;
HDC hdc;
void *bits;

bih.biSize = sizeof(bih);
bih.biWidth = width;
bih.biHeight = -height;
bih.biPlanes = 1;
bih.biBitCount = 32;
bih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bih.biSizeImage = 0;
bih.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bih.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bih.biClrUsed = 0;
bih.biClrImportant = 0;

hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

hbmp = CreateDIBSection(hdc, (BITMAPINFO*)&bih, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &bits, NULL, 0);

Bitmap bitmap(width, height, 0, PixelFormat32bppPARGB, bits);

Graphics graphics(bitmap);

graphics->DrawWhatever(...);

graphics->Flush();

SelectObject(hdc, hbitmap);

UpdateLayeredWindow(hwnd, hdc, ...
```

Comment: "you have to draw to a Bitmap, not an HDC" I was stuck by exactly this issue for months!