# c++ | Creating transparent parent window without using LWA_COLORKEY or effecting child windows

Tags: c++, winapi, window, transparent, alpha

I am trying to have my parent window transparent and my child window not effected by this transparency.
I did use LWA_alpha but that changed the transparency of the child window aswell which I do not want.
LWA_colorkey was working but I realised you cannot have something semi transparent, and it also halfs your fps so i dont want to use this as it doesnt work for what I want to make.

I have also used the dwextendmargin thing but this didnt seem to do anything.

Any help would be appriciated.
Here is the code for my windows and window's class

```
//Register Window Class
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {
    sizeof(WNDCLASSEX),
    CS_CLASSDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
    WndProc,
    0L,
    0L,
    hInst,
    NULL,
    NULL, NULL,
    NULL,
    _T("    "),
    NULL
    };

    RegisterClassExA(&wc);

    //Create Window

    wnd = CreateWindowExA( //parent window
        WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        wc.lpszClassName,
        "",
        WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        0, 0, //Pos
        sInfo->Width, sInfo->Height, //Size
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        NULL);

child = CreateWindowA(
        wc.lpszClassName, 
        "",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
        0, 0, 
        sInfo->Width, sInfo->Height, 
        wnd, 
        NULL, 
        hInst, 
        NULL);
```

Comment: You can't use `LWA_alpha` without the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style, which is missing in the code you have shown. Also, you are using `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` in the wrong parameter of `CreateWindowEx()`. In any case, when using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`, you can't apply transparency/alpha on the parent window without affecting the child window, too. It is an all-or-nothing deal. You will likely have to use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` instead so that you can apply a per-pixel alpha channel on just the portion of the parent window that is not covered by the child window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, I added WS_EX_LAYERED using the setwindowlong function. I shall take a look at updatelayeredwindow. I have looked at it previously and got a bit confused. Thank you

Comment: Why not use `WS_EX_LAYERED` directly in the `CreateWindowEx()` call?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah I have added that now

Comment: [LWA_ALPHA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) doesn't support this. Try [UpdateLayeredWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748142/my-code-which-uses-updatelayeredwindow-doesnt-work) as @RemyLebeau suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just switching to opengl as it was alot easier to do this task.

Answer (score -2):

Use this
`SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(255,0,0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);`

Comment: This is a fair bit thin as far as explanations go. A quality answer needs to, at least, identify the issue, and explain how the proposed solution addresses the issue.

Comment: @isaac goodborn  As I said this isnt going to help me with my issue as it halves my fps and cant do semi transparency

Comment: @isaacgoodborn This approach will work to make the parent window transparent as long as the specified color exists only in the parent window and not in the child window. But you can't apply partial alpha/translucency this way, only full transparency.